# Adding to the requirejs optimizer fileExclusionRegExp

Tags: regex, requirejs

Right now I'm using the following to exclude the r.js and build.js files from the optimized build.

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /^(r|build)\.js$/
```

How can I add to this to also exclude a directory or other files with specific extensions? Should I still be using this setting for that or is there another way to handle it. In particular I'd like to exclude those two js files and an entire directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine multiple excludes in one regex pattern with the `|` operator. For example:

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /.psd$|sound/
```

This excludes all `.psd` files, and the `sound` directory.
But keep in mind that it would remove any file, that contains `sound` in the absolute file name, so not just `.../sound/...`, but `.../sound.js` as well. I couldn't figure out how to include the slashes in the pattern. Normal escaping doesn't work here. So make sure you don't have such name collisions.